# SaveFileDialog does not save the filename or path

Tags: c#, winforms, path, filenames, savefiledialog

I want to use a SaveFileDialog and when clicking on the Save Button I want to save the filename and the path into seperate variables. Here is the code:

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialog1.FileName = "SaveFile";
        saveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = ".txt";
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt";
        saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save a Text File";
        saveFileDialog1.FileOk += saveFileDialog1_FileOk;
        saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void saveFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
            string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
            string name = saveFileDialog1.FileName;

            var test = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
        }
```

The dialog opens and it triggers the saveFileDialog1_FileOk Event but I get an empty string for the filename and the solution for getting the path (without filename) does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: look at this and you will quickly see where your problem / Issue lies.. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Tried but it does not even jump into the if branch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem you have is using 2 instance of `SaveFileDialog`.

You show one dialog and then try to read `File` from another dialog that is obviously empty.

Pay attention that in your button click you are creating a new local instance and show it, and then in `FileOk` you are using another instance that seems to be a form level member.

---

**Fix 1:**
You can simply remove  `SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();` because it seems you have saveFileDialog1 as a member of your form.

**Fix 2:**
You can use `SaveFileDialog` this way:

```
var sfd= new SaveFileDialog();
//Other initializations ...
//sfd.Filter= "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
//sfd.DefaultExt = "txt";

if(sfd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    MessageBox.Show(sfd.FileName);
    //ِDo something for save
}
else
{
    //Do something for cancel if you want
}
```

Then you can access to selected file using FileName property, for example MessageBox.Show(sfd.FileName);

Comment: @MethodMan Pay attention that the OP created a new local instance in `Button_Click` and show it, then in `FileOk` he uses `saveFileDialog1.FileName` that obviously different from the instance that he show.

Comment: @MethodMan And surely you are not blind, I wear glasses and my glasses point me to the point ;)

Comment: So how to avoid that? Everything works fine - just the saving does not work

Comment: I'll post the fix for you now

Comment: @Jackson30 Did you get the problem of your code? You are showing a dialog and reading FileName from other dialog that is obviously empty :)

Comment: By the way you should know, while you can only select on accepted answer, but you can kindly vote up for as many answer as you find helpful including the accepted one, by click on up arrow near the answer.  This makes answers more useful for future readers :)

Comment: Yes I did. I had too less reputation but now it works! :)

Answer (score 2):

Check this example from MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {
     Stream myStream ;
     SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

     saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"  ;
     saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2 ;
     saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true ;

     if(saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
     {
         if((myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
         {
             // Code to write the stream goes here.
             myStream.Close();
         }
     }
 }
```

You only have to check the return value of `saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()` to know whether the user has clicked ok or not.

Then, you can use the `FileName` property which contains the selected file path.

EDIT: To get the folder path of the file, you can use this:

```
string folderPath = new DirectoryInfo(saveFileDialog1.FileName).Name;
```

Comment: argumentexception at the folderpath. invalid format

Comment: What value does the `saveFileDialog1.FileName` property have?